# Cannot login to console

Tags: command-line, 18.04, login

I'm using my exact same user name and password that I use to login to my Ubuntu GUI to log in to the console prompt at `CTRL+ALT+F3`, but it constantly say login failed. I do not have capslock or numlock on.

Comment: No. I have tried all the answers. I wrote my password in the login field and it is exactly correct. (no keymap issues). My bash shell has nothing wrong, and I have checked my user name and password in my GUI settings.

Comment: I'm unable to comment as my reputation is too low. In the GUI open a terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`) try to `ssh <username>@localhost` and check if it accepts your username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Ubuntu has different username in GUI and command line. Just check the terminal for the correct username.